# Eagerloading with $with attributes freezes in laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

Easy said,
I have 2 models User and Profile
In the User model I have put this

```
protected $with = ['profile', 'subscription'];
```

and it works fine! but if I put this

```
protected $with = ['user'];
```

in the profile model the browser freezes and get the timeout!

What's the reason?

Comment: Isn't it self-referencing, hence recursively eager loading itself untill it either runs out of resources or time? I've never used Laravel, but that's what it looks like. You'd think Laravel would protect itself against that?

Comment: as stated, that is an endless loop of eager loading ... easy said